# Modem, Router, Switch configuration

Tags: router, switch, modem

I have two switches in different rooms, both wired to a router (LAN ports) which is in turn wired (WAN port) to a cable modem.

I want to switch from cable to DSL for cost reasons, but keep the router where it is.  I'd also like to use existing wiring to avoid fishing more cables.  Unfortunately, the phone line is not in the room where I want the router to be (where the cable modem is now).

Will the following work:

DSL modem in bridge mode to switch1 to switch2 to router (both lan and wan connections).  If not, I'll just fish a new phone line so I can put the DSL modem where the cable modem is now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is a little unconventional it should work. I've tried something similar before and did not get it to work, the PPOE server did not respond, however we had a fairly complex setup and also had firewalls in the mix. You may find the type and number of switches you have stops it working.

Assuming you just have the one uplink cable between the two switches, another option would be to use an Ethernet splitter, which would allow you to run two Ethernet devices over the one cable - basically it makes two Ethernet cables out of one - and you could then run your phone cable over that instead so your network device setup was more conventional. This could also be a fallback to trying to do the PPOE over the switches. See details here: https://superuser.com/questions/104050/difference-between-ethernet-splitter-and-switch

Bear in mind that either solution is a more complex setup, the first way more so, and complexity means less chance of someone else understanding how it's set up, more to troubleshoot when things go wrong leading to extended delays resolving issues, and higher probability of an incident occurring in the first place.